# Flutter/Firebase: Firebase Storage download stream restarts every time I setState

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, setstate

I use Firebase to manage multiple things in my Flutter application, I have a Product object which has multiple variables including an image for a Storage link.
I was using a Builder to build a widget for every object I have, inside the objects widgets there was also a Stream Builder to get the images links from Firebase Storage, my problem was that every time I use setState the screen refreshes and it causes the stream builder to restart and shows a CircularProgressIndicator again because that's what was shown when the connection state used to be equal to waiting.
To prevent that problem I tried to split my page in 2:

```
class _MenuDataState extends State<MenuData> {
  late DatabaseReference _dbref;
  Map<dynamic, dynamic>? map;
  String? dataString;
  late StreamSubscription disposeVar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref()
        .child("Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/Products");
    getProducts();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    disposeVar.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  getProducts() {
    try {
      net = false;
      disposeVar = _dbref.onValue.listen((event) {
        if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
          dataString = jsonEncode(event.snapshot.value);
          map = jsonDecode(dataString!);
          listOfProducts = [];
          productsBackup = [];
          images.clear();
          map!.forEach((idKey, element) {
            if (element['Img'].toString().isEmpty &&
                element['minQuantity'] == null) {
              listOfProducts.add(
                ProductObj(
                  id: int.parse(idKey),
                  title: element['Name'],
                  price: element['Price'],
                  picture: element['Img'],
                  quantity: element['Quantity'],
                ),
              );
            } else if (element['Img'].toString().isNotEmpty &&
                element['minQuantity'] == null) {
              getProductUrl(element['Img'])
                  .then((value) => images[idKey] = value);
              listOfProducts.add(ProductObj(
                id: int.parse(idKey),
                title: element['Name'],
                price: element['Price'],
                picture: element['Img'],
                quantity: element['Quantity'],
              ));
            } else if (element['Img'].toString().isEmpty &&
                element['minQuantity'] != null) {
              listOfProducts.add(
                ProductObj(
                  id: int.parse(idKey),
                  title: element['Name'],
                  price: element['Price'],
                  quantity: element['Quantity'],
                  minQuantity: element['minQuantity'],
                ),
              );
            } else {
              getProductUrl(element['Img'])
                  .then((value) => images[element] = value);
              print(images[element]);
              listOfProducts.add(ProductObj(
                id: int.parse(idKey),
                title: element['Name'],
                price: element['Price'],
                picture: element['Img'],
                quantity: element['Quantity'],
                minQuantity: element['minQuantity'],
              ));
            }
          });
          productsBackup = listOfProducts;
          clearSelected();
          setState(() {});
        } else {
          listOfProducts = [];
          productsBackup = [];
          images.clear();
        }
      });
    } on Exception {
      setState(() {
        net = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Menu();
  }
}
```

This returns the 2nd page which is too long, therefore I'm going to only show the imports and the Image I'm trying to show:

```js
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:application/FirebaseCloudFunctions.dart';
import 'package:application/ProductClass.dart';
import 'package:application/Widgets/dialogWidget.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'menuData.dart';

class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const Menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Menu> createState() => _MenuState();
}

var images = new Map();

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  int imageBox = 90;
  List<ProductObj> products = listOfProducts;

  Widget productTemplate(ProductObj productObj) {
    return Row(
        .
        .
        .
        Container(
        height: imageBox / heightScale!,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
          image: images[productObj] != null
              ? Image.network(images[productObj]).image
              : AssetImage("assets/products/None.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        )),
        foregroundDecoration: productObj.quantity == 0
            ? BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation,
              )
            : null,
      ),
      .
      .
      .
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      .
      .
      .
      GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        primary: false,
        itemCount: listOfProducts.length,
        itemBuilder: ((context, index) =>
            productTemplate(
                listOfProducts[index])),
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0 * widthScale!,
        ),
      ),
      .
      .
      .
    );
  }

}
```

Edit: I forgot to include the getProductUrl function, it was working fine when I was using a Stream builder, I used it as the Stream.

```js
Future<String> getProductUrl(String url) {
  return firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .refFromURL("gs://cips-mobile.appspot.com/")
      .child("Profiles")
      .child(url)
      .getDownloadURL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time setState is called the whole Widget is gonna be rebuild, this means that initState will be called again as well. You could make _dbref nullable and change the initState method so it checks _dbref before fetching the data.

```
DatabaseReference? _dbref;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if(_dbref == null){
    _dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref()
        .child("Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}/Products");
    getProducts();
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Wait, why should I give it the reference value when it's not null?
Shouldn't I put _dbref == null in the condition?

Comment: No problem, I just tried, the 2nd page is still not getting any Strings from the images Map.